# Error Installing phpmyadmin on CentOS

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, centos

I get the this error when i try yo install phpmyadmin on CentOS 6.5 VPS using this.

COMMAND :

```
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

ERROR :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.solarvps.com
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpmyadmin.noarch 0:2.11.11.3-2.el6.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 4.1.0 for package: phpmyadmin-2.11.11.3-2.el6.rf.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
           Installed: php-common-5.4.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.30-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Somebody please Help. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You've installed a more recent PHP version (5.4.30-1) from another source (@remi) than the officials (base) repository provides. Now you're trying to install the phpMyAdmin package, which depends on php-mbstring. php-mbstring is the actual problem here -- it's being automatically installed because phpmyadmin depends on it, but the version you're attempting to install isn't compatible with the rest of your PHP installation.

The solution is easy, though, since remi also provides phpmyadmin (quite a bit more recent version than you're attempting to install, too!). Just install phpmyadmin and php-common from the remi repository like you installed PHP. There are some instructions at http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en if you forgot, but you managed to install the upgraded PHP already so you should be able to get the remi phpmyadmin installed pretty easily.

OR....

Download phpMyAdmin from http://www.phpmyadmin.net and [uncompress it](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html) to your web root and forget about the package. php-mbstring isn't strictly required to run the application anyway, so you don't even need to worry about that part as long as you [meet the other requirements](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html).

Answer (score 1):

You installed php5.4 from remi repository.

phpmyadmin needs php to work; but you are installing phpmyadmin from the official repository and that phpmyadmin version needs php5.3.

I guess you don't want to go back to php5.3, so just run this command:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin
```

If you didn't add remi repositories to you CentOS, you will have to previously run:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

Comment: This solution worked flawlessly for me. Thanks Mikel!